# GenyMotion Plug-In for Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, genymotion

I have the GenyMotion plugin installed in Eclipse.  Boy, is it better than built-in emulator.  My question.  When I run the built-in emulator, I can set break points in my code, and the debug process works fine.  I cannot figure out how to do the same with GenyMotion.  I drag and drop the apk onto the emulator and run the app.  But Eclipse does not enter debug mode. How can I make the connection between Eclipse and GenyMotion? Debug configurations do not include an option to run GenyMotion, just the built-in emulator.
Help appreciated.

Comment: What the GenyMotion documentation say about that?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Run->Debug as->` menu to install your app on the Genymotion target instead of dragging & dropping the apk.

If you don't see the Genymotion as a target, it means it's not connected to the debug bridge (`adb`). This should happen automatically, but in case it doesn't, you can open a shell and try to (re)connect it:

```
adb connect 192.168.56.101
```

Replace the IP address with the address of your Genymotion instance (if different). You can find the address in the Genymotion Configuration app included in the VM.